# Intuition behind encoding double negation with bottom type Nothing

Tags: scala, termination, negation, type-theory, bottom-type

Shapeless encodes [double negation](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/85fb65f49352f7e80392b5aa8a749444e0532ce8/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/package.scala#L30) like so

```
type ¬[T] = T => Nothing
type ¬¬[T] = ¬[¬[T]]
```

that is

```
(T => Nothing) => Nothing
```

Miles [explains](https://milessabin.com/blog/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/)

> ...the bottom type (Scala’s `Nothing` type) maps to logical falsehood... negation of a type `A` (I’ll write it as `¬[A]`) to have as it's values everything which isn’t an instance of `A`

`Nothing` is also used to represent [non-termination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35850650/5205022), that is, computation that cannot produce a value

```
def f[T](x: T): Nothing = f(x)
```

Applying this interpretation to `(T => Nothing) => Nothing`, it seems to mean:

```
(          T                   =>                Nothing           )    =>          Nothing 
Assuming a value of type T,   then   the program does not terminate,   hence  it never produces a value.
```

Is this intuition correct? Are concepts of falsehood and non-termination equivalent? If so, why having a program that does not produce a value, which does not produce a value, means we have a value of T?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If so, why having a program that does not produce a value, which does not produce a value, means we have a value of T?

It doesn't. Logic arising from [Curry–Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) is not classical but [intuitionistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic). There is no [law of excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) `T ∨ ¬T` <sub>(but there is double negation of the law of excluded middle)</sub>.

`¬¬T` is not equivalent to `T`.

`T => ¬¬T` but not `¬¬T => T`.

> Are concepts of falsehood and non-termination equivalent?

No. Normally non-termination is ignored. According to Curry–Howard correspondence, statement is true when corresponding type is inhabited (i.e. there is a value  (term without free variables) of this type) and false when the type is not inhabited.

`Nothing` (or bottom type `⊥`) is not inhabited (it corresponds to `false`). If `T` is inhabited then `T => Nothing` is not inhabited (otherwise `Nothing` would be inhabited). If `T => Nothing` is inhabited then `T` is not (again, otherwise `Nothing` would be inhabited). That's the reason to define `¬T = T => Nothing`.

When non-termination is considered, this means that every type `T` is lifted to type `T'` consisting of elements of `T` and bottom value `⊥` ([divergence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698414/haskell-pattern-match-diverge-and-%E2%8A%A5), not to be confused with bottom type).